# How can I suppress the header for the first page in a chapter

Tags: header-footer, plain-tex

I'm trying to implement a macro that begins a chapter. I don't want to use latex or fancyhdr but only plain tex (for pedagogical reasons). The code is the following

```
\headline={\hfil{\tenrm\folio}\hfil}
\nopagenumbers
% Counters and macros for handling chapters
\newcount\fChapterNumber
\global\fChapterNumber=0
\def\fBeginChapter#1{
  % Initialization
  \advance\fChapterNumber by 1
  % Formatting
  \vfill\eject
  \hrule height0.7mm
  \vskip 5mm
  \centerline{\tenrm \noindent Chapter \the\fChapterNumber}
  \vskip 18mm
  {\tenbf \noindent #1}
  \vskip 35mm
}

% DOCUMENT %
\fBeginChapter{Analisis I}
blah, blah, blah, blah,...
\vfill\eject
blah, blah, blah, blah,...
\bye
```

As you can see the header will be printed in both pages, but I want it not to be printed in the first page of the chapter. I've been thinking and looking in the web unsuccessfully. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a conditional:

```
% Counters and macros for handling chapters
\newif\iffChapter
\newcount\fChapterNumber
\fChapterNumber=0
\def\fBeginChapter#1{
  % Initialization
  \global\advance\fChapterNumber by 1
  % Formatting
  \vfill\eject
  \global\fChaptertrue
  \hrule height0.7mm
  \vskip 5mm
  \centerline{\tenrm \noindent Chapter \the\fChapterNumber}
  \vskip 18mm
  {\tenbf \noindent #1}
  \vskip 35mm
}

\headline={\iffChapter\global\fChapterfalse\else\hfil{\tenrm\folio}\hfil\fi}
\nopagenumbers


% DOCUMENT %
\fBeginChapter{Analisis I}
blah, blah, blah, blah,...
\vfill\eject
blah, blah, blah, blah,...
\bye
```

The begin chapter command sets the conditional to true; when this is the case, the code in the header just switches the conditional to false, otherwise it prints the page number.

Notice that your `\global\fChapterNumber=0` is useless, while a `\global` should be in front of `\advance\fChapterNumber`.

If you want to set the page number at the bottom in the chapter starting pages, you can use the same idea:

```
\headline={\iffChapter\else\hfil{\tenrm\folio}\hfil\fi}
\footline={\iffChapter\hfil{\tenrm\folio}\hfil\global\fChapterfalse\fi}
```

and no `\nopagenumbers`; setting `\iffChapter` to false must be done by the footline code, as it is executed *after* the one in the headline.

Answer (score 0):

A simplistic way is to check for odd numbers.

```
\headline={\hfil{\tenrm\folio}\hfil}
\nopagenumbers
% Counters and macros for handling chapters
\newcount\fChapterNumber
\global\fChapterNumber=0
\def\fBeginChapter#1{
  % Initialization
  \advance\fChapterNumber by 1
  % Formatting
  \ifodd\the\fChapterNumber\vfill\eject
  \hrule height0.7mm
  \vskip 5mm
  \centerline{\tenrm \noindent Chapter \the\fChapterNumber}
  \vskip 18mm
  {\tenbf \noindent #1}
  \vskip 35mm
 \fi
}

% DOCUMENT %
\fBeginChapter{Analisis I}
blah, blah, blah, blah,...
\vfill\eject
blah, blah, blah, blah,...
\bye
```

However, to be correct you need to call your routines through the `output` routine.

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't answer the question. However, a `\null` before `\vfill\eject` is needed.

Comment: @egreg It is always best to add headers and footers in the OR i.e, `\output={
\shipout\box255 \advancepageno
\global\output={
\shipout\vbox{
\box255
\bigskip
\centerline{\folio}}
\advancepageno}
}`

Comment: The standard OR uses `\headline` and `\footline` for that purpose. The question was about suppressing the header in the chapter starting page.